# How to calculate disk usage filtering by pattern (e.g., *.JPG)?

Tags: linux, find, disk-usage, disk

How can I calculate disk space consumed only by some files of a directory recursively?

Answer (score 2):

`find -iname '*.jpg' -print0 | du --files0-from=- -h -c | tail -1`

1. `-iname` searches case-insensitively
2. `-print0` writes `NUL` instead of newlines
3. `--files0-from=-` reads `NUL` instead of newlines and reads from `stdin` instead of from arguments
4. `-h` outputs results in human-readable format (e.g., `1K` instead of `1024`)
5. `-c` outputs a grand total (e.g., `23G`)
6. `tail -1` will output only the grand total, suppressing individual file sizes

Comment: `-s` makes no difference in this case, because files may come from different, unrelated folders

Comment: Ah duh, you're right of course. I was thinking of it as a single argument to `du` but in this case it will be multiple. Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/stat

stat -LA blocks +blocks -- **/*.jpg(NDoN)
print $(( (${(j[+])blocks} + 0) * 512 ))
```

Would print the cumulative disk usage of all the files whose name ends in `.jpg` (including hidden ones with the `D` qualifier). Note that if there are several hard links to the same file, their disk usage will be counted several times (that's different from what most `du` implementations do).

If some of the files are or type *directory*, that will only count the disk usage of the directory files themselves, not of the files that can be found whilst traversing those directories (another difference with `du`).